# imageSnake function opencv - active contours

Tags: opencv

I am using OpenCV's snakeImage function and I vary my alpha, beta and gamma weights, but the initial contour doesn't move much. Am I doing something wrong? And, does anyone know how I should vary the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Google for tutorials.

Things like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5gqYY41HJA) should be helpful. Please trace back from that link.